# Referencing gcc with yocto recipe Makefile, unable to find stdint

Tags: gcc, makefile, embedded-linux, yocto

With Yocto 1.8 (fido), I am using a simple yocto recipe to run a `Makefile`.

```
SUMMARY = "PCI kernel module"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=4a0f8ad6a793571b331b0e19e3dd925c"

inherit module

PR = "r0"
PV = "1.0"

SRC_URI = "file://Makefile \
           file://COPYING \
           file://code.c \
           file://code.h \
          "

S = "${WORKDIR}"
```

And here is the `Makefile`.

```
obj-m := code.o

SRC := $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC)

modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC) modules_install

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c
    rm -f Module.markers Module.symvers modules.order
    rm -rf .tmp_versions Modules.symvers
```

When running `bitbake` on this recipe, I get the following compilation errors.

```
error: no include path in which to search for stdint.h
|  # include_next <stdint.h>
|                           ^
```

How do I configure this recipe to include `gcc` when compiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does does your `code.c` look like?

You can't use userspace headers in a module, and as far as I know, `stdint.h` is header from userspace.

Comment: That was the issue, replaced ```stdint.h``` with ```linux/types```.

Answer (score 0):

i think that is toolchain problem 
if your files are .c file  use  ${CC} in make file to compile in yocto.
files are .cpp use ${CXX} in make file

then it will compile with yocto default toolchain